# How to echo a message with a colon in it?

Tags: windows, batch-file

This seems really simple, but I am so stuck - been searching lots of nearly matching questions but just can't find the answer.

All I want to do is something like this:

```
echo c:\another\test\file.h(22,11) : warning 123: this is a test warning
```

But that gives the error: `: was unexpected at this time`.

So I tried:

```
echo "c:\another\test\file.h(22,11) : warning 123: this is a test warning"
```

Which produces: `"c:\another\test\file.h(22,11) : warning 123: this is a test warning"`. But I don't want the quotes. So I tried using the escape character "^":

```
echo c^:\another\test\file.h(22,11) ^: warning 123^: this is a test warning
```

But this had no effect. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

This line of code is within an if block, which appears to make a difference!:

`if exist "somefile" (
    echo c:\another\test\file.h(22,11) : warning 123: this is a test warning
)`

Comment: `echo c:\another\test\file.h(22,11) : warning 123: this is a test warning` works perfectly for me without any error. So I suppose, this is just a snippet of your code and the error comes from somewhere else. Please post the complete code.

Comment: I guess this line of code is placed within a parenthesised block of code, so the `)` is interpreted as the closing one, which makes `: warning 123: ...` an invalid command; try to escape the `)` by `^)`...

Comment: @aschipfl - yes you are right, it was inside an `if (...here...)` block, I had no idea that would have had an effect on the echo statement - no wander it was so difficult. Moved it out of the if block and it works fine :) ... feel free to add that as an answer. I'll update my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your command line is placed within a paranthesised block of code, like this, for example:

```cmd
if exist "c:\another\test\file.h" (
    echo c:\another\test\file.h(22,11) : warning 123: this is a test warning
)
```

So the closing `)` in the `echo` command line is interpreted as the closing one of the entire block, leaving the portion `: warning 123: this is a test warning` as an invalid command line.

To solve it, you need to escape the `)` by preceding a caret `^`, which is `cmd`'s escape character:

```cmd
if exist "c:\another\test\file.h" (
    echo c:\another\test\file.h(22,11^) : warning 123: this is a test warning
)
```

Therefore the colon `:` in front of `warning: ...` is actually not causing the problem here.